# Bash function script

Tags: bash, function, scripting

I am having a lot of difficulties with one of my homework assignments and was wondering if I could get some help on this.

Here are the instructions

```
1.Sets an alias for the less command so that it will display line numbers when l is used and the filename is passed:
       a. Ex: l filename
2.Reads the   /etc/passwd  file, use the variable Line to store the data
3.Uses a function to process the data read from /etc/passwd
       a. Use the global variable, Line, when processing the data
       b. Information passed to the function from the main script is:
              1)The username field number
              2)The UID field number
       c. The function will determine which UIDs are less than 100 and then write those to a file named           results.hw5.txt in the user’s home directory
              i.use the form: user’s ID = UID /// user’s name = username
                     ii.Ex: user’s ID = 0 /// user’s name = root
       d.Any variables created within the function must be local.
4.Uses the alias created in Step 1 to read results.hw5.txt
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

function func1
{
local filename=/etc/passwd
local results=~/My_Scripts/results.hw5.txt
while IFS=: $line -p uid _ user _ 
do
((uid<=100)) && echo "user id = $uid /// username = $user" > $results
done < $filename
}
alias l='less'
line=$(read)
func1
l $results
```

Comment: You need something like `while read Line; do ...; done < /etc/passwd` outside the function.

Comment: The function is supposed to take the username and UID as parameters.

Comment: So you need to read the line into `Line` in the loop, then extract the username and UID from this, then call `func1 $username $uid`

Answer (score 1):

> while IFS=: $line -p uid _ user _ 
>   do

This contains multiple errors. `$line` can't be expected to be a valid command and the `-p` option to `read` requires an argument (if that is even what the `-p` is for here).

The instructions to create an alias are misdirected, but the apparent lesson here is that you can include an option in the alias definition.

```
alias l=`less -option`
```

(I'm not giving away the precise option to use here. Look it up.)

Your specification says to process each `passwd` entry inside the loop. So the loop needs to look something like

```
while read -r line; do
    funcname  # argument "$line" is global implicit
done</etc/passwd
```

The guidance to use a global variable to pass information to the function is also highly dubious.

The parsing of `line` should happen inside the function - again, a doubtful design, but here goes.

```
funcname () {  # prefer POSIX function definition syntax
    # split on colons into positional parameters
    local IFS=:
    set -- $line
    # now, $1 is account name, $2 is UID, etc
    :
}
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the instruction to pass field numbers as parameters to the function. Maybe it wants `$1` and `$2` to be parameters you can pass in to identify which fields to extract? (Hint: `${$var}`. And you obviously need to capture the function arguments before overwriting the positional parameters with `set`.)

As an aside, you are violating the instructions by not writing the file into the user's home directory. Maybe omit the `My_Scripts` subdirectory.